# How to make multiple independent subscriptions using angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript

What is flatMap() ,switchmap(),pipe()? which one is best in following scenario? once both the response is received I want to call next method.

```
this.jobService.getEditableText('admins',compareFile["0"].path,1000).subscribe(data=>{
this.file1=data['data'];})
this.jobService.getEditableText('admins',compareFile["1"].path,1000).subscribe(data=>{
this.file2=data['data'];})
```

Comment: You could use `combineLatest` on both observable and check if both has values then call the third one

Comment: it is deprecated i guess

Comment: if you are using RxJS 6 then use `combineLatest` if RxJS 7 then `combineLatestWith`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are probably looking for a `combineLatest` or a `forkJoin`.
We can't know for sure because we don't know have the code of the Function `getEditableText()`.

*What operator we should use?*

`forkJoin` if we need to wait until both input observables *complete*.

`combineLatest` if we want to have emissions as soon as both observables *emit* once (emit not complete!).

From the question you have done I highly suggest you to take a look again at the RxJS pipes. Main reason is when you manually subscribe to Observables you should also unsubscribe as soon as you don't need them anymore to avoid memory leaks.
Based on your code, I would do something like this:

```
const subscription = combineLatest([this.jobService.getEditableText('admins',compareFile["0"].path,1000), 
this.jobService.getEditableText('admins',compareFile["2"].path,1000)])
.subscribe(console.log)
```

now as soon as both functions return the result, you should get a console log with an array of results: [res1, res2].

Remember that as soon as you don't need the subscription active anymore (e.g when you destroy the component) you need to unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks:

```
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

If you get some *deprecation warnings*, it's probably related to how you are passing the observables as arguments to the combineLatest operator.
combineLatest is not deprecated at all.
In the newest version you should pass an array of observables, not just observables.

e.g
Older RxJS versions:

```
combineLatest(one$, two$)
```

Newer versions:

```
combineLatest([one$, two$])
```

*Why not `flatMap/mergeMap` or `switchMap` ?*

In this case, you probably don't need `flatMap` (which is just an alias of `mergeMap`) or `switchMap`, since apparently those two function calls are not related (there is no dependency).
In other words, I don't see why we would need to wait for the first observable emission to then call the second observable. We can just execute everything in "parallel".